# 'hadoop jar' command exits before the job completes?

Tags: bash, hadoop

I have seen the following behavior several times and cannot figure out why it happens.

I have a bash scripts like this:

```
echo "execute UidGenerator"

hadoop jar foo.jar com.xyz.platform.UidGenerator input_path output_path

echo "execute UidAggregator"

hadoop jar foo.jar com.xyz.platform.UidAggregator input_path output_path
```

The UidAggregator should not start until UidGenerator finishes. However, I saw the following logs and the 2nd job starts while the 1st job is still running.

```
16/08/22 07:46:42 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 68%
16/08/22 07:47:29 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 69%
16/08/22 07:49:01 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 70%
execute UidAggregator
```

I've seen this behavior several times. The shell command follows a 'hadoop jar' command starts while the job is still running (job tracker shows the job is running successfully).

Has anyone seen this behavior? I thought bash scrip should not execute next command until previous commands exit.

Comment: Are you sure that the first command isn't finished when the second begins, or is the output behavior possibly caused by the Hadoop process' logs not flushing properly? Is `UidGenerator` a `Tool`?  How do you await completion in `run()`?

Comment: @Suriname0 I am sure the first command, in this case the hadoop job, hasnt finished. The jobtracker shows it's still in the middle of reduce. And the HDFS still shows the '_temporary' folder.

Comment: in that case I repeat my earlier question: Is `UidGenerator` a [`Tool`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/util/Tool.html)? How do you await completion in `run()`?

Comment: @Suriname0 UidGenerator is a class with main() to execute a job and use 'job.waitForCompletion(true)'.

Comment: That's really strange; have you put in any sanity checks like logging after `waitForCompletion` terminates? What's the `getJobState()` after waitForCompletion returns?